# How to make a descriptive tree out of categorical variables with Python Decision Tree Classifier

Tags: python, decision-tree

Every time we fit a tree classifier using Python (sklearn), we should convert categorical data into numerical data. After converting, if we would like to see how the tree actually looks like, we can barely observe that since all we can see are numbers.

So how should I do if I would like to plot a descriptive tree (just want to see where it splits, which category it uses.) using Python? It seems like R doesn't have this kind of issue, but is there any solution for Python?

Answer (score 0):

Good question and a really good exercise at explaining models. Here is my input.

1. Prepare your data as per your requirements. One hot encode the categorical data as usual. If the attribute is ordinal, use appropriate pre-processing.
2. Fit a decision tree using sklearn. Perform hyperparameter tuning as required. The second half is important because sometimes if the data is large, the plotted decision tree would become difficult to peruse.
3. Now plotting the tree can be done in various ways - represented as a text or represented as an image of a tree.

3.1 For text representation

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
model_instance = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model_instance.fit(X,y)
text_representation = tree.export_text(model_instance)
print(text_representation)
```

3.2 For plotting the tree

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8)) # I like 15,8 personally
tree.plot_tree(model_instance,feature_names,class_names,filled=True) 

# if you'd like to save the tree as .png

fig.savefig("Tree.png")
```

Useful sources:

1. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html
2. https://mljar.com/blog/visualize-decision-tree/

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I tried these two methods but I didn't get the split information of original features, they are still numbers. For example:
|--- feature_37 <= 0.50
|   |--- feature_23 <= 0.50
|   |   |--- feature_38 <= 0.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 0
|   |   |--- feature_38 >  0.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- feature_23 >  0.50
|   |   |--- feature_0 <= 51.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|   |   |--- feature_0 >  51.50
|   |   |   |--- class: 1
|--- feature_37 >  0.50
|   |--- class: 0
What is feature_37? is there any way to map it back to original features?

Comment: Hi Anuj, I tried "tree.plot_tree(dct,data_x.columns, data_y.columns,filled=True)" but it never worked. I got error "index 37 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1". dct is the model I fitted. I just realize that I could use "feature_37" to figure out which feature it is using with number 37, but it will be better if I could still make the second option work.

Comment: the new feature such as feature_37 etc are to my understanding the one-hot encoded features. so if you have n unique values for your categorical attribute, then you now have feature_n, feature_n-1 etc as new features.